# MVC3 (Razor) Passing Model Data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm making Memo web application.

and the main page contain 'Create and List and Modify' functions.

But I don't know how to pass Model (for create) and List (for List) to View(Razor) from controller.

this is my note model,

```
[Table("note")]
public class Note
{
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Content is required")]
        [DisplayName("Note")]
        public string content { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "User ID is required")]
        [DisplayName("User ID")]
        public string userId {get; set;}
        public Boolean isPrivate { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AttachedFile> AttachedFiles { get; set; }

}
```

I tried,

## 1)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     var notes = unitOfWork.NoteRepository.GetNotes();
     return View(notes); 
}
```

Then, in view,

```
@model Enumerable<MemoBoard.Models.Note>
//I can not use this, because the model is Enumerable type
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.userId)
```

So, I made viewModel

## 2)

```
public class NoteViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Note> noteList { get; set; }
    public Note note { get; set; }
}
```

In Controller,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var notes = unitOfWork.NoteRepository.GetNotes();
    return View(new NoteViewModel(){noteList=notes.ToList(), note = new Note()});
}
```

and In View,

```
@model MemoBoard.Models.NoteViewModel
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.note.userId)
```

it looks well, BUT in source view, it's showing

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="User ID is required" id="note_userId" name="note.userId" type="text" value="" />
```

the name is **note.userId** not **userId**.

List this case, how should I do to make working?

Please advice me.

Thanks

**[EDIT]
(First of all, thanks for all advices)**

Then, How can I change this controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Note note) 
{
    try
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        unitOfWork.NoteRepository.InsertNote(note);
        unitOfWork.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    }catch(DataException){
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again please");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

If I change parameter type to NoteViewModel, then how should I do for valid check?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(NoteViewModel data) 
{
    try
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) <===
```

Comment: In regard to case 2 it is ok to have a field named note.userId as long as you are using the same (or similar structured) viewmodel to recieve the postback. The modelbinder will take care of binding the fields...

Comment: @Jan Hansen Thank you for your comment, could you review my edited question again please? I need a little more your help ^^

Comment: As webdeveloper mentions in a comment to the answer below, RedirectToAction clears the state of the viewmodel, hence you should use **return View()** when there are model errors. Other than that ModelState.IsValid should work just fine with the NoteViewModel as input for your action method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@model Enumerable<MemoBoard.Models.Note> 
//I can not use this, because the model is Enumerable type 
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.userId)
```

You can use it in `foreach` loop or return list and use it in `for` loop

```
the name is note.userId not userId.
```

It's normal, this made for model binding

Try this:

```
Html.TextBox("userId", Model.note.userId, att)
```

Comment: @Expertwannabe `att` is `htmlAttributes`, for example `new { id="myattr" }`. You can write `@Html.TextBox("userId", Model.note.userId)` if you don't need them.

Comment: @Expertwannabe About your update: with `RedirectToAction` you will lose `ModelState` error, write `return View();`, this will execute GET `Index` action. And you can create empty collection in `NoteViewModel` for your list.